# Why isn't the Entity Framework package installed in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, nuget

I installed Visual Studio 2013, but no matter what I do, I can't install the Entity Framework package

```
The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'EntityFramework'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package EntityFramework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is a problem with your internet connection: `[https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The source at nuget.org is unreachable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969234/the-source-at-nuget-org-is-unreachable)

Comment: But my internet has no problem !!!!!

Comment: nuget.org recently turned off tls1.0 and 1.1. .NET's HTTP client does not use TLS1.2 by default unless the application targets a certain version of the .NET Framework or higher (4.6 maybe?)   If Visual Studio 2013 runs an older version of the .NET Framework, then NuGet's HTTP Client may not use TLS1.2 and therefore be unable to talk to nuget.org.  You might need to look for registry settings or something to force TLS1.2 on, since it might not be on by default. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-org-will-permanently-remove-support-for-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-june-15th/

Comment: The registry keys needed to enable TLS1.2 for older .NET Frameworks are listed here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that at all. Thank you very much.
Yes, the problem is:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/